# Create object in thread A, use in thread B. Mutex required?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

I have been reading different things on multithreading, C++, proper synchronization and locks to prevent race conditions. One question has not been answered for me, however:
**Is there a mutex required if I create an object in thread A, but use it exclusively in thread B afterwards?**

In other words, I know that I don't need a mutex to prevent race conditions - do I need a mutex to serve as a memory barrier (or other potential problems)?

A very basic example to visualize what I mean

```
struct Object {
    void do_stuff();
};

Object o;
std::thread worker_thread([&o](){
    while (alive)
        o.do_stuff();
}).join();
// `o` is never used outside worker_thread
```

I would be happy if you could also recommend me articles / books where I can read more into this topic and/or the right keywords to search for these kinds of scenarios.

Comment: if only one thread is using the object,*and you can count on that*, then you should have no problem.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is fine, you don't need a `mutex`.

Creating a thread sets a memory barrier, so it is safe to access `o` via the reference you passed to `worker_thread`.

§ 30.3.2.2-6 - [thread.thread.constr]

> The completion of the invocation of the constructor synchronizes with the beginning of the invocation of the copy of f.

While `worker_thread` is running, obviously you may not access `o` in the thread that created it (as you said).

Joining a thread sets a barrier too, so after `worker_thread` has joined, you can access `o` again in your main thread.

§ 30.3.2.5-4 - [thread.thread.destr]

> The completion of the thread represented by *this synchronizes with (1.10) the corresponding successful join() return.

For further reading:

- Anthony Williams wrote a good book on parallel programming (*C++ concurrency in action*)
- Bjarne Stroustrup's book (*the C++ programming language*, 4th edition) has two nice chapters on concurrent programming.
- Jeff Preshing has a nice blog about many of these topics; check out preshing.com

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much. I was actually reading C++ concurrency in action but could not find these information. But I guess that is because I did not make the connection between thread creation and memory barrier in my head

Comment: welcome.. It's sometimes challenging to find the common denominator since these are different topics usually covered in different chapters